# period must be a specialization of ratio in C++17 chrono library?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono

I'm clearly too stupid to use the C++17 `<chrono>` library.  Compiling the following...

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
    using duration = std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::seconds>;
    using timepoint = std::chrono::time_point<clock, duration>;
    timepoint t0 = clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        timepoint t = clock::now();
        duration d = t-t0;
        double seconds = d.count();
        std::cout << seconds << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get...

```
/usr/include/c++/8/chrono:319:16: error: static assertion failed:
                                  period must be a specialization of ratio
      static_assert(__is_ratio<_Period>::value,
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second type parameter to `std::chrono::duration` needs to be a ratio (ticks per second), not another duration (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). `std::chrono::seconds` is a duration. You'd want this instead:

```
using duration = std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1> >;
```

FYI `std::chrono::seconds` is basically a `std::chrono::duration<some integer type, std::ratio<1> >`; your duration type is sort of like `seconds` but with a floating point number instead of an integer.

Comment: Thanks.  I finally figured out that it was `std::chrono::duration<double>` which I believe is short for what you wrote.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Yup it's the same; the default value for the second type parameter is `std::ratio<1>`.